# Adding labels to Setting titles with API

Tags: settings-api

If I add a setting using `add_settings_field()`, it doesn't create a `<label>` around the title so that it can be clicked to focus on the field. Some of the core settings do this, but they just add it in the raw HTML rather than using the settings API. Is there any way to add labels with the settings API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass last parameter `$args`, if you want `add_settings_field` to output `<label>` use `label_for' argument, see code snippet below

```
<?php add_settings_field( 'my-id', 'Test Filed', 'mamaduka_test_field', 'general', 'my-section', array( 'label_for' => 'my-test-field' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The Codex doesn't give any clue what the possible options are, and it's not in the function's phpdoc either. I looked through template.php and it looks like 'label_for' is the only argument. I'll update the Codex.

Comment: @Ian you should check core for `do_settings_fields`, but unfortunately there is no full list of `$args`

Comment: Yeah, I did. `label_for` is the only one mentioned in `do_settings_fields()`. I updated the Codex with the info.